# $R$-recursion for the A007165

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, generating-functions, recurrences

- Let $a(n)$ be [A007165](https://oeis.org/A007165) i.e. number of $P$-graphs with $2n$ edges. Here ordinary generating function $A(x)$ satisfies
  $$
  A(x) = \frac{(1 + xA(x))(1 + 2xA(x))}{1 + 2xA(x) - (xA(x))^2}
  $$
- Let
  $$
  R(n, q) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{q+1}(-1)^{[j\operatorname{mod}2 = 1]\cdot[q\operatorname{mod}2 = 1]}R(n-1, j), \\
  R(0, q) = 1.
  $$
  Here square bracket denotes [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

I conjecture that $$R(n, 0)=a(n+2).$$

Here is the PARI/GP program to check it numerically:

```
a_upto(n)=Vec(1/x*serreverse(x*(1+2*x-x^2)/((1+x)*(1+2*x)+x*O(x^(n-1)))))
R_upto(n) = my(v1, v2, v3); v1 = vector(n + 1, i, 1); v2 = v1; v3 = vector(n + 1, i, 0); v3[1] = 1; for(i = 1, n, for(q = 0, n - i, v2[q + 1] = sum(j = 0, q + 1, (-1) ^ (j % 2 && q % 2) * v1[j + 1])); v1 = v2; v3[i + 1] = v1[1]); v3
test(n) = concat(1, R_upto(n)) == a_upto(n+2)
```

Is there a way to prove it?